# Representing a linear operator as a diagonal block-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Problem**: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $\varphi\colon V\to V$ be a linear operator. Suppose there are subspaces $U\subset V$ and $W\subset V$, such that $V=U\oplus W$, $\varphi(U)\subset U$ and $\varphi(W)\subset W$. Prove that there is a basis for $V$, such that the operator $\varphi$ can be represented as a diagonal block-matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

**So far**: I'm aware of the following theorem:

*Theorem*: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $f\colon V\to V$ an operator. Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be all the unique eigenvalues of $f$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. The operator $f$ is diagonalizable
2. The space $V$ has a basis that consists of the operator $f$'s eigenvectors
3. There are 1-dimensional subspaces $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ of $V$, such that they are invariant under the operator $f$ and $V=U_1\oplus \ldots \oplus U_n$
4. $V=E(\lambda_1, f)\oplus \ldots \oplus E(\lambda_m, f)$
5. $\dim V=\dim E(\lambda_1, f)+ \ldots +\dim E(\lambda_m, f)$.

So I want to show that $f$ is diagonalizable (or is this stronger than what the question wants?), i.e. there is a basis for $V$ such that the associated matrix is diagonal (what is the connection between this and being diagonal in the sense of a block-matrix?). By assumption $U$ and $W$ are invariant under $\varphi$ and $V=U\oplus W$, so we almost have (3), but obviously they need not be 1-dimensional. I'm completely stuck at this point...

Comment: You are thinking too hard, and yes this may not be diagonalisable. This is a direct property of the direct sum...

Comment: Yeah I thought the diagonal requirement was too strong. I still don't see why it's obvious, can you formalize it?

Comment: Just use an adequate basis for the decomposition $V = U \oplus W$(both are finite dimensional) I really believe you just went too far, you should make "tabula rasa" and write what the definitions give you

Comment: Supposing $u$ is a basis for $U$ and $w$ is a basis for $W$, then $u\cup w$ is a basis for $V$. In this case am I correct in saying that $A_1$ is the matrix representation for $\varphi_U$ in the basis $u$ and the same for $A_2$ with $\varphi_W$ in the basis $w$?

Comment: Yes, now you just have to write it properly

Answer (score 0):

Being diagonalizable is stronger to being represented by a diagonal by block-matrix. This question is more elementary than the theorem you are trying to use.

Look what happens if you take a basis adapted to the decomposition $V = U \oplus W$, i.e. such that $(e_1 , \dots , e_{\dim(U)})$ are a basis of $U$ and $(e_{\dim(U) + 1}, \dots, e_{\dim(U) + \dim(W)})$ is a basis of $W$ (show that such a basis exists and is well a base). Then try to understand what's the shape of the matrix in this basis.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. I'm just trying to figure out how to formalize it.